# Passing function to new function to read file

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a problem with reading some massive text-files.

I firstly define reading my text file as follows:

```
def reader(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='latin-1') as thefile:
        contentsofthefile = f.read()
    return contentsofthefile
```

Now I want to have another function, that uses the above function, such as:

```
def remover(filename):
    a = reader(filename)
    for line in a:
        do this
```

This yields the following problem:

```
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: 'In search of lost time  - CHAPTER///1 \nThe characters, plotlines,  ...."
```

It seems that it attempts to read the entire file as the filename?

Comment: How do you call `remover`?

Comment: The code above would not result in that error, can you post a minimal example and the actual results? Calling `f.read()` on the third line would raise a NameError because f is not defined yet.

Comment: Not sure about `contentsofthefile = f.read()` it should be `contentsofthefile = thefile.read()`

Comment: Do you pass the `contentsofthefile` to the `remover(filename)` function?

Comment: If it's a massive text file, why are you reading the entire thing into memory instead of just iterating over the file line by line?

Comment: @doctorlove as "remover(thefile)"

Comment: you are definitely passing the wrong thing to reader.

Comment: @trotta No, that I was I am trying to do... I want the contents of the file, which my reader function reads, and then use that in my remover function.

Comment: can you show us where you call remover?

Comment: @bravosierra99 print(remover(filename))

Comment: sorry, we need to see the value of filename.  like an example.  Because you are passing in the wrong value for filename, and it's propogating in all of your functions.

Comment: @Moe: I don't really get your answer. It seems like you're passing the content of the file (as you return it with your `reader(filename)` function) to your `remover(filename)` function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on debugging your code. You seem to be using a very long string as a file name, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to process the file line by line, there's no reason not to *read* the file line by line as well. You don't really need a `reader` function, but it can be as simple as

```
def reader(filename):
    return open(filename, encoding='latin1=1')
```

Then to *use* `reader` inside `remover`:

```
def remover(filename):
    with reader(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            ...

remover("somefile.txt")
```

Comment: I 100% concur with this, but that being said it does not seem like this is his issue.  His issue is what he's passing to the remover function, because it's somehow the contents of his file and not the filename.

Comment: And I am clearly showing an example of `reader` being used by `remover` *taking* a filename, not the contents of a file. The original question doesn't show what actual code produced the error (which is obviously due to passing the contents of the file to `reader`).